# Calculate route with traffic

Tags: android, ios, traffic

I need to calculate routes but them with traffic impact on that, like a route from A point to B point in 10 minutes but it will give 30 minutes with traffic.. How I can calculate it on Android and iOS ? Need I do with one traffic API ?

Thanks !